# How to share with remote PDF file in Android?

Tags: android, pdf

I have a URL which points to some PDF file. The thing I want to achieve is to share it with some app. Sharing not a link, but the PDF file itself. The question is how to achieve this? With my investigation I came to the following conclusion:

1. Download it using Retrofit
2. Save it inside device
3. Get somehow the path of the file and share it

Is it correct path to solve the problem? Maybe there are other, more easy solutions?

Comment: This seems to be a good way to share PDF

Comment: @JudeOsbertK How do you think where should I store my PDF file? External or internal storage? It contains some private data. What is the right choice? If I save it in internal storage, can I access it and share it?

Comment: If you wanna share the file then what is so private on it?

Comment: You can store the file where you want and at sharing use a FileProvider.

Comment: @blackapps I want to enable sharing feature because user can send that file to some app like Dropbox, Google Drive. Even if it is private. Can you tell me where should I store such a file? Internal storage or external? And do I need runtime permission for any of the storages?

Comment: Save in internal. No permissions needed.

Comment: @blackapps But, if I am going to enable share feature and that file is located in internal storage, can it be shared? I mean, internal storage is more secure. Can other apps access my file from it?

Comment: My god i already told you to use internal memory and use a FileProvider at sharing. Internal memory is for your app only. There is nothing more to tell.

Comment: @neo Save it in your cache. Good stuff: No permissions required for your app. No user interaction. Bad Stuff, it can be accessed by the user if he/she wants to. If you are concerned about the privacy, try some encryption on the file. I would say copy it to internal only on demand.